# import data from excel with multiple values per observation

Tags: r, statistics, format

I am using `Prism` normally and unfortunately the dataset is too big for `Prism`. I want to perform a two way ANOVA in a dataset with 5 timepoints (variables) and four observations. However, each observation contains more than 700 values. I want to find out if there is a significant difference between the observations at different time points. If I try to export it as .txt or .csv the program does not understand that all the values belong to this observation.

If I manage to import the data correctly, I wanted to use these instructions http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/two-way-anova-test-in-r#compute-two-way-anova-test-in-r-for-unbalanced-designs.

[image: Image of what raw data looks like]

This is what the raw data looks like. I connected the cells in the first column to include all the values in one observation but this does not work.

Comment: When reading your data into R you will get a column for each of the values. To perform a statistical analysis on this data in R (or any other statistical programming language I know) you have to reshape your data to long format. Personally I would use `tidyr::pivot_longer` but see [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) for other options.